# SQLite wear levelling

Tags: python, sqlite, yield

I am performing sqlite INSERTs to a flash device and I have experienced Wear Levelling that starves a higher proprietary thread when performing similar writes via base fileio that were fixed with yields. Is there a way to insert yields into this INSERT operation when stepping the sql statements?

I understand that sqlite writes an entry and not the whole file, so it would have to seek, write and possibly flush. Adding a yield after the seek and the write will avoid starvation in the other higher priority thread.

As I said, I have managed to reproduce this issue via basic fileio and the yield fixes the problem.

Comment: `yield` isn't a process-scheduling construct. Just because its use in one context happens to have side effects that fit with what you're trying to accomplish doesn't make it the right tool for achieving those side effects.

Comment: ...particularly, when you say "a higher priority thread", do you mean higher CPU priority, or higher IO priority? If you want to set IO priority, you should be using `ionice`, not `nice`.

Comment: Try using [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).